# How to specify attribute in .Net 2.0

Tags: vb.net, json.net, .net-2.0

I have the following class But Im getting the error:
**Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement.**
The error is on line:  `<JsonProperty(PropertyName:="error")>`
note this is for .Net 2.0

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Public Class FastWayError
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="error")>
    Public error_ As String
    Public generated_in As String
    Public data As Object
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the line continuation character as follows:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Public Class FastWayError
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="error")> _
    Public error_ As String
    Public generated_in As String
    Public data As Object
End Class
```

It is the underscore after "error")>

Comment: I was puttting the _ directly after the > e.g. >_  Will mark this as answer in few minutes